# Ошибка при запуске любого кода в Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всем привет. Ошибка при выполнении любого кода на C# в консольном шаблоне Visual Studio.

При запуске кода, даже банального WriteLine появляется в окне вывода появляется подряд много таких сообщений:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4651,5):
> warning MSB3026: не удалось скопировать
> "C:\Users\user\source\repos\App6_cycles\App6_cycles\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App6_cycles.exe"
> в "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App6_cycles.exe". Повторная попытка 1
> начнется через 1000 мс. Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу
> "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App6_cycles.exe", так как этот файл
> используется другим процессом. "App6_cycles (17496)" блокирует этот
> файл

А в конце выдает ошибку:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4651,5):
> error MSB3027: не удалось скопировать
> "C:\Users\user\source\repos\App6_cycles\App6_cycles\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App6_cycles.exe"
> в "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App6_cycles.exe". Превышено допустимое
> число повторных попыток (10). Произошел сбой. "App6_cycles (17496)"
> блокирует этот файл

С чем связана эта ошибка и как её избежать?

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас уже запущена ваша программа. Поэтому вижуалка при билде не может заменить старый экзешник на новый. Первое сообщение об этом явно говорит.

Comment: Вы уверены, что это консольное приложение? Обычно такая проблема бывает с оконными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас уже запущен экземпляр вашей программы, который мешает MSBuild-у перезаписать .exe файл на новый во время билда.

> Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\App6_cycles.exe", так как этот файл используется другим процессом. "App6_cycles (17496)" блокирует этот файл.

Скорее всего, вы забыли закрыть какое-нибудь окно консоли после одного из запусков, и теперь оно блокирует файл.